# User settings or custom config file for application settings?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have a few application-level settings that must be changed at run-time, especially being set on starting the application the first time. Once set up, every user that starts the application accesses these "common" settings. Users also have their own user-level settings.

Users can start the application in 3 ways:

1. Application is installed locally
2. User accesses the app via RDP
3. User accesses the app via Citrix

As application-level settings are read-only at runtime, what is the best practice to get/set application-level settings and also adhering to UAC?

Comment: What's the problem with `User` scope settings in application settings (.settings files)? They are not read only and they are in user scope.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Wouldn't every user that starts the app need to configure the app with the same settings as the user settings are saved locally for each user?

Comment: If I understand the requirement correctly, you can use user settings. They have default values. Also the user can change the value at run-time and use their preferred values. Or maybe I didn't get the requirement?

Comment: @RezaAghaei The application-level settings should be changed the first time a user starts the app. All following users will use the same settings.

Comment: I see, there is no problem to satisfy the requirement. Have you ever tried user settings? (open `.settings` file in design-mode and add an entry to it and change the scope to `User`) then you can let the user edit your setting object in a property grid or some other controls. `Properties.Settings.Default` is the setting object containing all properties. Those properties which are in `Application` scope are read only and `User` scope properties are editable. Also each it respects to values set by each user in windows.

Comment: Was the user settings what you were looking for?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I'm currently using user settings but it's not a solution. I have to roll-out my own solution whereby I read/write application settings in the `CommonDocuments` folder where all users will have access to.

Comment: User settings store in user folder and you don't  need to do anything extra yourself.